# how to assign counter value to expandable list view button

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandable list view and each one of view has button. I need to set a tag to each of the button like button1(count 0), button1(count 1), button1(count 2)....... I tried incrementing count each time but it is setting some random counter value.

I am suspecting that I am doing counter++ in wrong place please some one suggest me where I can increment the counter value.

**Universally assigning  counter:**

```
int counter = 0;
```

**In getChildView() method**

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
   if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater parentInflater = (LayoutInflater) mctx.getSystemService(mctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = parentInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemname_child_layout, null);
        holder.button = view.findViewById(R.id.childrecordbtn);
 } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
 }

 holder.button.setTag(counter);

 holder.button..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          int tag = view.getTag();
          Log.i("Tag Value = ",tag);
        }
 }
 counter++;
 return view;
}
```

Above code returning some random values after button click.

**Output :**

```
Button1 : "Tag Value : 24"
Button2 : "Tag Value : 25"
Button3 : "Tag Value : 113"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the definitation of `getChildView()`:

```
getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

That means in your code, `i` is the `groupPosition` and `i1` is the `childPosition`. You should only rely on these parameters to determine the content of each row rather than using an external counter.

You can get an one-dimensional array index by the follow calculation:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int j = 0;j < i; j++)
{
       sum += getChildrenCount(j);
}
final int arrayIndex = sum + i1;
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("Tag Value = ",arrayIndex);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Ricky. I agree with you but my scenario is little different I need to store a some text in to an array with the exact position of that button. Since I am using expandable list view it is nothing but two dimensional array so i don't want to store text always depend on child position.

Comment: So you want your button known about both `groupPosition` and `childPosition` right? Actually `setTag()` is not necessary. You can directly use `i` and `i1` within `onClick`.

Comment: tag is useful when many Views share the same event listener. In this case since you set a new listener for every single button anyway, each listeners can be different so you can use `i` and `i1` directly within the listener.

Comment: Besides, I think you are missing `view.setTag(holder);` within the body of `if (view == null) ` so that you can get the holder back when the view is not null (resused). Without this you will end up with `NullPointerException` at some point

Comment: Yup thanks, but how I will store the text field value in the exact button position without counter?? I am using one dimensional array to store text field value. If i use i and i1 value then I need to use two dimension array right?? but I don't want to store it in two dimension array.

Comment: You can calculate the one dimensional index base on `i` and `i1`. Use a for loop to sum up the `getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)` with `groupPosition` from  `0` to `i - 1` then add `i1`

Comment: I mean, I have one dimensional int[] a = int[10]; now i need to assign some unique position to each button like btn1 - pos1, btn2-pos2..........  so that if click on btn1 it will pick up the pos1 and stores the value in the **pos1** index of array **a**

Comment: see my edited code to calculate the one dimensional index

Comment: Consider the expandable list as a 2-d array. Let say you want to convert `[[0,1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8],[9]]` to `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. To find the index of let say `7`, you add up the lengths of all sub-arrays before it and also the index of itself in its own sub-array, i.e. `[0,1,2,3].length + [4,5].length + [6,7,8].indexOf(7) = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7`